# laravel controller - global variables (fields)

Tags: php, laravel, methods, controller, global-variables

I would like to define global variables in my controller:

```
class AdminController extends /BaseController {

    private $destination = 'uploadeimages';  <-- this is what I mean

    public function foo() {

        return $destination;   <-- this is returning error    
    }
}
```

But if I use that variable in one off controllers method, it is returning error:

> Undefined viarable - destination

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Use `$this->destination`. Or use class constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace that with this:

```
return $this->destination;
```